# Error when trying to migrate comments to a clean D8 site: What's wrong with my .yml file?

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm trying to migrate content from my current D7 site to a Drupal 8 installation.

I've managed to import some of the nodes, and now I want to import the comments for those nodes.

Every time I click on "run" (.../admin/structure/migrate/manage/importarComentarios/migrations/importar-comentarios/process/run) I get an error:

[image: error]

**What am I doing wrong?**

### This is my migrate_plus.migration.importarComentarios.yml file:

id: importar-comentarios
label: Comments

migration_tags:
  - CSV

migration_group: importarComentarios

```
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: 'public://csv/exportar-comentarios-genericos.csv'
  header_row_count: 1
  delimiter: ','
  enclosure: '"'
  keys:
    - id
  column_names:
    0:
      nid: 'nid'
    1:
      created: 'created'
    2:
      body: 'body'
    3:
      autor: 'autor'
    4:
      cid: 'cid'
    5:
      titulo: 'titulo'
    6:
      mail: 'mail'

destination:
  plugin: entity:comment

process:
  entity_id: nid
  subject: title
  'comment_body/value': body
  'comment_body/format':
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: "html"    
  # Migrate our custom field
  field_mail: mail    
  field_nombre: autor
  status:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: '1'    
  created: created
  nombre: autor
  email: mail
  # The comment type (aka the comment's bundle).  
  comment_type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 'comentario'      
  # The type of entity we're attaching this comment to.  
  entity_type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 'node'
  # The field we should attach this comment to. This is a field on your node.
  field_name:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 'comentarios'

migration_dependencies: {}
```

### And this is the migration overview:

This is the overview
[image: This is the overview]

This is the destination
[image: This is the destination]

This is the process
[image: This is the process]

And when clicking the source, I get:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

### My configuration is:

My content type is called contenido
[image: My content type is called contenido]

And these are the fields of my comments
[image: And these are the fields of my comments]

And my contenido content type has a comentarios field for comments
[image: And my contenido content type has a comentarios field for comments]

Comment: The unexpected error thing is the equivalent of a windows blue screen. Check your server error logs and recent errors in Drupal logs and post them to see what is happening exactly.

Comment: Alternatively enable verbose error logging with backtrace in the settings and try the things that cause the unexpected error page again.

Answer (score 0):

```
  keys:
    - id
```

The yml is using a key 'id' that is not defined in the column_names. Since you have a 'nid' column, I suggest changing 'id' to 'nid'.